# MySQL index doesn't help in IN

Tags: php, mysql

If I write this query,

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `smth` WHERE d_id = 9
```

it checks one row instantly. But when I use `IN`, for example

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `smth` WHERE d_id IN (9, 3)
```

it checks all rows. What should I do instead of IN if index doesn't help there?

Comment: yes I am very curious to know the answer too

Comment: Why do you think it checks all rows? Can you post the output of the EXPLAIN SELECTs?

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586381/mysql-not-using-indexes-with-where-in-clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL 5.1 does have a `range` join type that optimizes `IN` predicates.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html

However, the MySQL optimizer may have determined that your `d_id` column contains values 9 and 3 in so great a majority of rows that it decided it would be cheaper to read the whole table than to read the index and then the table.

By analogy, if you read a book and you want to find every page that has the word "the" would you go to the index at the back of the book, look up "the," and flip to each page in turn?  Or would you just read the book cover to cover because almost every page is guaranteed to have that word on it?

Comment: It was actually superb explanation. I've just inserted a lot of rows and tried to use IN again and now it checked only few rows not all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your table doesn't contain many rows. If your table contained more rows it probably would use the index. Here's an example from a table with one million rows:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE x = 9;
1, 'SIMPLE', 'table1', 'const', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'const', 1, ''

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE x IN ( 9, 3);
1, 'SIMPLE', 'table1', 'range', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', '', 2, 'Using where'
```

In both cases the primary key index is used.