# Delete many rows from a table using id in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am a Linux admin with only basic knowledge in Mysql Queries

I want to delete many table entries which are ip address  from my table using **id**,

currently i am using

```
DELETE from tablename where id=1;
DELETE from tablename where id=2;
```

but i have to delete 254 entries,so this method is going to take hours,how can i tell mysql to delete rows that i specify,coz i want to skip deleting some entries out of this 254.

Deleting whole table and importing needed entries is not an option.

Comment: id is a number so something like `DELETE from tablename where id<254 and id>3;` or whatever would work.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

The best way is to use `IN` statement :

```
DELETE from tablename WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...,254);
```

You can also use `BETWEEN` if you have consecutive IDs :

```
DELETE from tablename WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 254;
```

You can of course limit for some IDs using other WHERE clause :

```
DELETE from tablename WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 254 AND id<>10;
```

Comment: Range (`>` and `<`) is better than `IN` in terms of performance as we discovered in our application today. Use the explain statement and see how `IN` does not use indexes.

Comment: Don't worry about how your DBMS use INDEX or not... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586381/mysql-not-using-indexes-with-where-in-clause to understand why sometimes using INDEX will be longer than doing a full table scan!

Answer (score 10):

how about using `IN`

```
DELETE FROM tableName
WHERE ID IN (1,2) -- add as many ID as you want.
```

Answer (score 7):

if you need to keep only a few rows, consider

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id NOT IN (5,124,221);
```

This will keep only some records and discard others.

Answer (score 6):

If you have some 'condition' in your data to figure out the 254 ids, you could use:

```
delete from tablename
where id in 
(select id from tablename where <your-condition>)
```

or simply:

```
delete from tablename where <your-condition>
```

Simply hard coding the 254 values of id column would be very tough in any case.

Comment: like @tom10271 said this should produce "You can't specify target table in FROM clause" in MySQL

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might make it a bit easier, you could obviously use a script to generate this, or even excel

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN (
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Others have suggested `IN`, this is fine. You can also use a range:

```
DELETE from tablename where id<254 and id>3;
```

If the ids to delete are contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Use `IN` Clause

```
   DELETE from tablename where id IN (1,2);
```

OR you can merge the use of `BETWEEN` and `NOT IN` to decrease the numbers you have to mention.

```
DELETE from tablename 
where (id BETWEEN 1 AND 255) 
AND (id NOT IN (254));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 256;
```

Try This.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps:

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE tablename.id = ANY (SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE id = id);
```

Comment: For *10.1.37-MariaDB* I got error: "Error SQL (1235): This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery".

Answer (score 1):

All responses are good but have one big wrong assumption that **id** is a **number type**. You must know column type in where deleting is performing. If this is a **CHAR TYPE** or similar string, You must ADD **"** like this:

```
DELETE from tablename WHERE id IN ("str1", "str2", "text",..., "string" );
```

In other case query will not perform and will return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id > 0;
OR
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id <255;
```

It deletes id from 1 to 254