# Delete multiple records from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete, delete-row

I have a dashboard of product.On dashboard it display all product details.There is check box to delete multiple product at a time.
 For that I am using this code:

```
    $id=array('0'=> 'ab','1'=> 'bc','2'=> 'cd','3'=> 'de',.......);
    $packids=implode("','", $id);
    $packids= ('ab','bc','cd','ef',.....);// n numbers of record
    $sql = "DELETE from app_and_page where `Package` IN ($packids) and `user_created`=$uid";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );
```

This query is deleting only one row.How can I delete all the selected rows at a time.

Comment: All `$packids` are for  `$uid` ? or `$uid` is different?

Comment: check your `user_created=$uid"`

Comment: All $packids are for $uid  Yes. User add multiple product and can delete.

Comment: @hungrykoala $uid comes correct.It is deleting only one row not all what I given in query

Comment: Please explain your table data and $uid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete many rows from a table using id in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504020/delete-many-rows-from-a-table-using-id-in-mysql)

Comment: Is `$packids` an array? If yes, you need to `implode(',', $packids)`.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer yes.But i am not getting desired out put.It is deleting one row only instead of all what I given.

Comment: I assume `$packids = array('ab', 'bd', .....);` or change it to `$packids = ['ab', 'bc',....];`

Comment: @MilanChheda yes after implode I am passing  this like $packids= ('ab','bc','cd','ef',.....).

Comment: @Urvashi - Are `ab`, `bc`, etc the ids?

Comment: If yes, then it should be `$packids="'" . implode("','", $id) . "'";`

Comment: @MilanChheda Echo query comes like DELETE from app_and_page where `Package` IN ('ab','bc','cd','de') and `user_created`=2 but delete only one row

Comment: @all Now working Problem is while implode extra space is coming.After removing it is working fine.Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing the issue in pack ids just try this
In place of

```
$id=array('0'=> 'ab','1'=> 'bc','2'=> 'cd','3'=> 'de',.......);
$packids=implode("','", $id);
$packids= ('ab','bc','cd','ef',.....);// n numbers of record
$sql = "DELETE from app_and_page where `Package` IN ($packids) and `user_created`=$uid";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );
```

Use this

```
$id=array('0'=> 'ab','1'=> 'bc','2'=> 'cd','3'=> 'de',.......);
$packids=implode("','", $id);
$packids="('".$packids."')";
$sql = "DELETE from app_and_page where `Package` IN $packids and `user_created`=$uid";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );
```

It will work for you.

**EDIT**

Try like this

```
$sql = "DELETE from app_and_page where trim(`Package`) IN $packids and `user_created`=$uid";
```

Comment: Echo query comes like DELETE from app_and_page where Package IN ('ab','bc','cd','de') and user_created=2 but delete only one row

Comment: Just make sure that in Package there is no space in value like 'ab ' or ' cd' if so then use trim(`Package `)

Comment: Right .That was the problem.Thanks.Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`$packids= ('ab','bc','cd','ef',.....);// n numbers of record
 $sql = "DELETE from app_and_page where Package IN (substr($packids, 0, strlen($packids)-1)) and user_created=$uid";
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );`

Try this one.
I think you have to remove last comma from our packids string.

Comment: Echo query comes like DELETE from app_and_page where Package IN ('ab','bc','cd','de') and user_created=2 but delete only one row