# MySQL - Not using index for a big IN condition

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am trying to select about 800,000 rows in 7+ millon table using this query

```
 SELECT * FROM news_completed USE INDEX (brand_id) WHERE `brand_id`IN (6346,6324,364,6460,6341,6495,6340,6438,6496,6439,6345,6344,6343,6497,6446,6450,6445,6443,6338,6440,6492,6449,6435,6609,6493,6347,6442,6339,6437,6444,6436,6494,6342,6575,6574,6576);
```

Column brand_id is indexed but index is not used, even if I force use in the query. EXPLAIN statement: http://hpics.li/209e767

But, if I reduce the number of brands within the IN to half (aprox), then the brand_id index is used:
http://hpics.li/02f9822

Could you explain me what is this limitation and how I can avoid it? Or build my query in a more efficient way?

Thanks a lot,
Maxime.

Comment: I think we'd need to see proper DDLs and the EXPLAIN.

Comment: There is no restriction in the number of elements for the IN clause. Try to use EXPLAIN to get more information of the query.

Comment: I can't post an image with the EXPLAIN because I am new here :(
Using EXPLAIN I see that no key is used in the first case, and eliminating most of the brand_ids I then see that the brand_id index is used (using EXPLAIN)

Comment: Hi, I could post the EXPLAIN statements through links, I hope this helps.

Comment: You should post the execution plan as **formatted** text, not as an image.

Comment: This is a table, I don't know how to embed it into my post that's why I uploaded images. How should I format that text? thanks.

Comment: no one has an idea? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think with a FORCE INDEX I solve my problem even though I am not sure why index is not used by default.. 
I guess the optimiser thinks a full scan is better than a range scan, my tests makes me think it is wrong..

[MySQL not using indexes with WHERE IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586381/mysql-not-using-indexes-with-where-in-clause)