# WHERE clause slows down SELECT query significantly

Tags: mysql

I've got a simple query:

```
SELECT distinct state FROM customers WHERE country = 'us'
```

The idea is to get a list of states in the US that customers live in.

I've got around 800k rows, and an index on `state` and on `country`.  This query takes about 4s to run, which is way too long, as this needs to be in real time.

If I remove the `WHERE` clause, it figures it out almost instantly.  I looked into why, and when I run an `explain` on the query with the WHERE clause, it does not use the `state` index.  When I get rid of the WHERE clause, it starts using the state index again.  Why is this happening, and is there a way I can make it use both indexes?

I've browsed other questions on SO that seem similar, but it seems like for the ones I found, they were very complicated queries, and the solution was just a query rewrite.  This is so simple, though, I think it gets to the heart of the problem.

Update:

I have found that if I do an index on `us_state`, it works in about .5s, which is good enough.  I'd like to have multiple parts to the `WHERE` clause at some point, though, so making a compound index for all the parts is still not optimal.  As such, I leave this question open looking for a better solution.

CreateTable

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
`country` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`st` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `state` (`state`),
KEY `country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: just checking, because sometimes the mysql query planner is bonkers, do you get a similar result for `SELECT state FROM customers WHERE country='us' GROUP BY state` ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately `group by` takes around 4s as well.

Comment: i would suggest you add a common numerical index for country='us' and do a where on that. MySQL is pretty bad when it comes to dealing with anything text. Numbers, it can handle well. Also, what are the cardinalities for those indices?

Comment: post your `CREATE TABLE` statement please

Comment: Hi Alex, I made this table a long time ago using HeidiSQL.  It is a complicated table with about 20 columns. What part of it do you want to see?

Comment: I want to see *create table* statement. to get that you should run this query  `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers`

Comment: Either you have an index on a column that doesn't actually exist, or you mangled something when you redacted the create table for SO. Can you show the *actual* output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: your create statement has no sense. either you are not attentive or you are lying :-) And I did not ask for table *all_wellbore_data* I did ask for *customers*

Answer (score 0):

This answer should provide you with a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/586834/3299157

In short, run the Analyze function and see if that speeds it up.

```
ANALYZE TABLE CUSTOMERS;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: unfortunately this did not reduce the query time.