# Slow MySQL query when using ORDER BY id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, cancancan

I have a very slow query where the first part is created by a gem (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan, it creates the select and the inner query) and where I add an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for a cursor based pagination.

```
SELECT `spree_products`.*
FROM `spree_products`
WHERE `spree_products`.`id` IN
    (SELECT `spree_products`.`id`
     FROM `spree_products`
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `spree_vendors` ON `spree_vendors`.`id` = `spree_products`.`vendor_id`
     WHERE `spree_vendors`.`active` = TRUE)
ORDER BY `spree_products`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 50;

=> 50 rows in set (1 min 3.48 sec)
```

This are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `spree_products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `available_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `permalink` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `count_on_hand` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_spree_products_on_vendor_id` (`vendor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37209248 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

```
CREATE TABLE `spree_vendors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4413 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

(I removed unneccessary fields to keep it tidy)

The `EXPLAIN` on the query above returns this:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type   | possible_keys                             | key                               | key_len | ref                            | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | spree_vendors  | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY                                   | NULL                              | NULL    | NULL                           | 3465 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | spree_products | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,index_spree_products_on_vendor_id | index_spree_products_on_vendor_id | 5       | _hubert_test.spree_vendors.id  | 8613 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | spree_products | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                   | PRIMARY                           | 4       | _hubert_test.spree_products.id |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

When I remove the `ORDER BY` the query is fast:

```
SELECT `spree_products`.*
FROM `spree_products`
WHERE `spree_products`.`id` IN
    (SELECT `spree_products`.`id`
     FROM `spree_products`
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `spree_vendors` ON `spree_vendors`.`id` = `spree_products`.`vendor_id`
     WHERE `spree_vendors`.`active` = TRUE)
LIMIT 50;

=> 50 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I keep the `ORDER BY` part from the outer query, but remove the `WHERE` part from the sub query, the query also is fast:

```
SELECT `spree_products`.*
FROM `spree_products`
WHERE `spree_products`.`id` IN
    (SELECT `spree_products`.`id`
     FROM `spree_products`
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `spree_vendors` ON `spree_vendors`.`id` = `spree_products`.`vendor_id`)
ORDER BY `spree_products`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

I tried adding a composite index to `spree_vendors.id / spree_vendors.active`, but that didn't help.

Any idea, on how to optimise this query?

#### UPDATE 1:

A `JOIN` Variant of this is also slow. The `DISTINCT` is added by the gem to prevent duplicate records in case you don't select all columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `spree_products`.*
FROM `spree_products`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `spree_vendors` ON `spree_vendors`.`id` = `spree_products`.`vendor_id`
WHERE `spree_vendors`.`active` = TRUE
ORDER BY `spree_products`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 50;

=> 50 rows in set (1 min 43.13 sec)
```

Without the `DISTINCT` the query is fast.

#### UPDATE 2

It was pointed out, that using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` inside the sub query returns the whole table. But when using an `INNER JOIN` it still is slow:

```
SELECT `spree_products`.*
FROM `spree_products`
WHERE `spree_products`.`id` IN
    (SELECT `spree_products`.`id`
     FROM `spree_products`
     INNER JOIN `spree_vendors` ON `spree_vendors`.`id` = `spree_products`.`vendor_id`
     WHERE `spree_vendors`.`active` = TRUE)
ORDER BY `spree_products`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 50;

=> 50 rows in set (1 min 3.98 sec)
```

Comment: The problem is WHERE IN, not ORDER BY. Rewrite to INNER JOIN or at least WHERE EXISTS. If your framework cannot then use raw SQL.

Comment: PS. By the text logic your WHERE IN and the whole subquery must be removed at all - it simply checks that `spree_products.id` is not NULL.

Comment: ...which is the same as 'inner join'

Comment: And note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: I've updated the question and added a JOIN version of it. @Akina what do you mean by "it simply checks..."? The sub-query selects all `spree_products` that have a `spree_vendor` that has `active = TRUE`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Your subquery returns ALL `spree_products.id` present in a table. So you have `WHERE spree_products.id IN (complete spree_products.id list)` which is true until `spree_products.id` is NULL.

Comment: [Here is an interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47097813/14648997) on a similar subject

Comment: In updated query - WHERE condition converts LEFT joining to INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Akina ahh, now I see your point! But when I change the sub-query to use an inner join, it still is slow, see the updated question

Comment: Incidentally, the LEFT JOIN is interpreted as an INNER JOIN in this instance (because of the WHERE clause), so it doesn't return the whole table. (Oh essentially a repeat of what Akina said above)

Answer (score 0):

Given that `id` must be PRIMARY, your query must be functionally identical to this:

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] p.*
  FROM spree_products p
  JOIN spree_vendors v
    ON v.id = p.vendor_id
 WHERE v.active = 1
 ORDER 
    BY p.id ASC
 LIMIT 50;
```

This would benefit from an index on p.vendor_id, and perhaps v.active.

Comment: close, the framework adds a `SELECT DISTINCT` to it. Without the distinct the query is fast, otherwise slow

Comment: Do you have the index?

Comment: Running an explain on your query and adding a DISTINCT, it returns this
`|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | index  | index_spree_products_on_vendor_id            | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                     |  499 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary |` and this index
`|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_spree_vendors_on_id_and_active | PRIMARY | 4       | _my_table.p.vendor_id    |    1 |    10.00 | Using where; Distinct        |`

Comment: there is an index on `p.vendor_id`, and I tried adding one to `v.active`, it makes no difference, the query is still slow.

Comment: I'm stumped then. This is a tiny dataset; results should be instantaneous, with or without ORDER BY.

Comment: oh sorry, that was a copy-paste error, I've updated it