# Mysql does not use index

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-delete

I have table that has composite PK.

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_value_copy` (
    `tag_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `value` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`, `created_at`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

When I execute following query

```
DELETE FROM tag_value_copy WHERE (tag_id, created_at) IN ((1,2), (2,3), ..., (5,6))
```

mysql does not use index and goes through all rows. But why?

[image]

---

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tag_value_copy WHERE (tag_id,created_at) in ((1,1518136666), (2,1518154836))` do NOT use an index as well.

[image]

---

UPD 1

```
show index from tag_value_copy
```

[image]

---

UPD 2

```
explain delete from tag_value_copy where (tag_id=1 and created_at=1518103037) or (tag_id=2 and created_at=1518103038)
```

[image]

Comment: Show execution plan using `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I have updated my question with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL not using indexes with WHERE IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586381/mysql-not-using-indexes-with-where-in-clause)

Comment: I am not sure, I even can`t use 'force index' on delete query. If I change delete from ... to select * from .... Be sure, it uses an index.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your claims on a table created with your DDL. Both `select` and `delete` use the same PK index. There must be something you're not telling us. What is the cardinality of `tag_id`? How many `...`s are in your `in` list?

Comment: It looks like the cardinality of tag_id is super low, but the query suggest that it should be able to use created_at. Maybe MySQL simply has not optimized this usage of `IN` ?

Comment: I have added some more info. It's really strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The Why -- MySQL's optimizer does nothing toward optimizing `(a, b) IN ((1,2), ...)`.

The Workaround -- Create a table with the pairs to delete.  Then `JOIN` using an `AND` between each of the 2 columns.

None of these help:  `OR`, `FORCE INDEX`.

Why the heck do you have PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`, `created_at`) ?  Are you allowing the same tag to be entered multiple times?