# In MySQL 'USE INDEX' is not working But 'FORCE Index' seems working fine

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 

SELECT * FROM table_name

--  FORCE INDEX(dummy_date)

 USE INDEX(dummy_date)

where dummy_date 

between '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'

AND name='something';

ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD INDEX `dummy_date_index`(`dummy_date`)
```

When I execute this query then indexing is not working but if I use `force index` then its working with index. Please let me know the correct approach to use the index for millions of rows.

Comment: MySQL uses index by date only when the range is below 10 days. USE INDEX won't help. If you are sure that index usage will improve then force it.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than [MySQL not using indexes with WHERE IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586381/mysql-not-using-indexes-with-where-in-clause) --

Use a better index and don't bother with USE or FORCE:

```
INDEX(name, dummy_date)
```

Anyway, if most of the table is in that month, then using `INDEX(dummy_date)` is less efficient than scanning the table.