# MySQL date range query indexing is working for limited range only

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT * FROM table_name
where dummy_date 
between '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'
-- between '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-20'
AND name='something';
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD INDEX `dummy_date_index`(`dummy_date`);
```

if dummy_date is between 20-25 days then query used indexing for 700,000 records but if it is more than 25 days then query is not using indexing and doing full table scan. please let me know the correct approach to utilize index.

Comment: Can you please add table schema? Also this has no relation to phpmyadmin, that is just a UI. It is as related as your browser is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In MySQL 'USE INDEX' is not working But 'FORCE Index' seems working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66007286/in-mysql-use-index-is-not-working-but-force-index-seems-working-fine)

Comment: How is this different to your last question?

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(name, dummy_date)
```

would be better.

It is right for the Optimizer to avoid an index that is not very selective.  There is overhead in using an index.  There is also overhead in skipping rows during a table scan.  The Optimizer has to pick which is the "lesser of two evils"; sometimes it does not pick the right 'lesser'.

Comment: but name column value is similar for most of the records .

Comment: @ashutoshkumar - That does not matter.  To be effective, put the `=` columns first.  After the first `range` column, nothing else will be looked at.